# Analytic continuation of representations between $SO(4)$ and $O(1,3)$ Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, analyticity

$SO(4)$ transformations and Lorentz transformations are isomorphic in a neighbourhood of their identity element. Can anyone shed light about how this could lead to the analytic continuation of their algebra representations?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_Lie_algebra) et seq.

Comment: Thanks, I see the relation to the WP passage, but since SO(4) and analytic continuation are not directly mentioned, could you maybe elaborate a bit on the relation between $SO(4)$ and $SO^+(1,3)$ sharing the same complexification $SO(4,C)$ and their analytic continuation in this case so  I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. As a warmup, write the 3 commutation relations of so(3) and o(1,2), instead, and scale suitable is into selected generators to continue form one algebra to the other, to see the point. You can then extend to your problem, explicitly or implicitly. It is a trivial exercise.

Comment: Yes, I think I see the point. Can it be summarized saying that when complexifying the Lie algebra of an orthogonal group, the same thing is obtained regardless the signature you started with?i.e.:$\mathfrak{so}(3,1)\otimes \mathbf C =\mathfrak{so}(4)\otimes \mathbf C =\mathfrak{so}(2,2)\otimes \mathbf C$ . So that the corresponding real Lie algebras can be uniquely analytically continued in the complex plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, by way of explication of the [WP discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_Lie_algebra) of the Lie algebras involed.

so(4) ~ so(3)×so(3) has these two ideals, whose generators are ***A*** and ***B***, respectively. Taking ***(A+B)/2*** and ***(A-B)/2***, respectively, yields so(4) in the conventional real antisymmetric basis.

Taking, instead, ***J=(A+B)/2*** and ***K*** = *i* ***(B-A)/2***, yields so(1,3) of the Lorentz group, with its peculiar diag(-1,1,1,1) metric.

I have skipped anything relating to the global properties of the group, etc, since you only wanted the complexification part.

Comment: Ok. BTW could you address my last comment above?

Comment: I think so, but I  am only a physicist... In practice, by judicious insertions of multiplicative i's, you may end up on any sequence of minuses in the metric on the right hand side of the commutation relation, and so invariance of an arbitrary diagonal invariant...  1111 for so(4),  -1 111 for so(1,3) , -1 -1 1 1 for so(2,2)... I think each one of these alternatives is unique, to the extent another one would be transformable to these 3 by complex similarity transformations.

Comment: Thanks. For some strange reason mathematicians seem to not be willing to get into these issues.